# Notebook does random device connect/disconnect sounds (not USB)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, device-manager, system-sounds

I've some Problems with my HP EliteBook 820 G4. As soon as I close the lid, Windows makes a "Device Connected"-Sound. Then, as soon as I open it up, it makes a "Device Disconnected"-Sound. When I leaf it closed, at some time, it begins making this sounds at completely random times. Sometimes it does this sounds 1 or 2 times in a minute, then it does it 5 or 6 times in a minute.

I've installed an "USBLogView"-Utility from nirsoft to keep track of USB-Devices that are connecting or disconnecting from the notebook. I've tested it with a flash drive; this is logging just fine. But closing it, hearing the sound, opening it back up does no entry in this USBLogView-Application at all.

I've also tried  to do this:
https://superuser.com/posts/1096961/revisions
--> But same results.

I've googled this issue, so I found a common problem with Bluetooth or Wireless Chips/Cards. I tried to disable all Network and Bluetooth devices AND all USB-Host Controllers, but this hasn't stopped the notebook from making this annoying sounds...

I want to find out, why the Notebook is making this sounds and why I cannot log this, not with the tools of the operating system, nor with third-party applications.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does your webcam work reliably? You might have a bad connection inside the laptop. The only USB device in the screen is the webcam. When you move the screen you are breaking the connection.

Comment: The Webcam is working correctly. I've set the laptop to do nothing if closed, then I opened the camera app to check if it works, what it does. So next I slowly closed the lid until the monitor went black, not further. As soon as the monitor went black the sound rings, I open it back up, and the camera had no black screen or whatever at all, it's just working the whole time. So I don't think it's the camera. Also if it where a USB-Device, the "USBLogView"-Utility would have had an entry for it, but it didn't. So the problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you for your answer, I didn't check that before.

Comment: I have some new insights to share.
The sounds do not appear at random times like I said before. After precisely 60 sec it begins making this sounds annoyingly often and permanently until I open it. When I close it, it first makes a _connected_ sound, then it's quiet for exactly 60 seconds. After that time it starts making this sounds in turns, beginning with the _disconnected_ sound, and it won't stop until I open it.
I've made a Video, so you see/hear it on your own.
I think it's a Software issue because no hardware issue is that predictable.
Link to the Video:

Comment: Sounds.mp4 (~ 83MB) https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1sf1mosv31q0cl/Sounds.mp4?dl=0